# Windows Azure phone number format

Tags: azure, phone-number

I wanted to register on Windows Azure, so it asks me my phone number but when I enter it, i do not receive any message on my phone.

I live in France (+33) and the placeholder value in the phone number field is "4 17 91 23 45 67" so 11 numbers, I tried something like 3 36 11 22 33 44 (didn't work), and many other format, do you know which format is right for my country (or why it doesn't work) ?

Answer (score 0):

France is definitely on the list of countries where Windows Azure is commercially available (http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/faq/).

What you want to do is completely omit the country code (+33) from the phone # provided.

When you select France as your country during sign up, the +33 is assumed so if your full # was 33 + 1 22 33 44 55, you would select France as your country and then put 1 22 33 44 55 as your telephone #.